# FastMM does not show leaks even if Inc file is properly set

Tags: delphi, fastmm

An old project landed in my hands. It has 130000 lines of really bad code (no try/finally all exceptions swallowed, thousands of global variables). I expect thousands of memory leaks. However, FastMM4 shows nothing on shutdown. No message box, no txt log file.

I use the same FastMM settings (inc) for all other projects, it works. So, I am not suggesting FastMM (or its settings) is broken. I think just can't handle this impressive amount of leaks. A friend of mine told me that on a large project also with many leaks, it needed 5-10 minutes until FastMM generated the txt log.

Verifications:

- FastMM is declared on the first line in DPR.
- I manually created a line of code to generate a leak.
- EnableMemoryLeakReporting is defined (see listing below)
- I am in debug mode (Map file generation is set to "Detailed")

Any tips on how to get the log?

---

```
{$define UseCustomFixedSizeMoveRoutines}
{$define UseCustomVariableSizeMoveRoutines}
{$define NoDebugInfo}
{$define ASMVersion}
{$define CheckHeapForCorruption}
{$define DetectMMOperationsAfterUninstall}
{$define FullDebugMode}

  {$define RawStackTraces}
  {$define LogErrorsToFile}
  {$define LogMemoryLeakDetailToFile}
  {$define ClearLogFileOnStartup}
  {$define LoadDebugDLLDynamically}
  {$define AlwaysAllocateTopDown}
  {$define SuppressFreeMemErrorsInsideException}

{$define EnableMemoryLeakReporting}
  {$define HideExpectedLeaksRegisteredByPointer}
  {$define RequireDebuggerPresenceForLeakReporting}
  {$define EnableMemoryLeakReportingUsesQualifiedClassName}
{$define EnableMMX}
  {$define ForceMMX}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hint: You may post your findings as an answer (and accept it)

Comment: Note that you may also use FastMM5, which imho is easier to configure (in code) - https://github.com/pleriche/FastMM5

Comment: Please refine your questions before posting, and don't [edit them](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/73408092/3) changing their scope and content, so that any answer would stay in sync with the question posted. It adds confusion to confusion.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez - I haven't changed the question at all. I only added extra information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the reason: The person who wrote the code uses `KillTask` to terminate the program (followed by `Application.Terminate`).
I removed that code. Now FastMM generates the log file which is 12MB! I have to fix them. Lucky me!

---

Personal thoughts: When I got the solution, I was sad, and I thought maybe this was not supposed to be a post for StackOverflow. On a second thought, it is fine. We learned something today: how **not** to write programs :)
Also, we learned that there are myriad of magic ways in which a mad programmer can break a program and we will spend days to figure our his mad-ways.

(In my language we have a saying: "When a mad-man throws a rock in a lake, 10 smart people cannot retrieve it", which means that it is easy to do something stupid, it is difficult to fix it.)

Comment: Well if it makes you feel any better, you helped at least one other person: *me*. Couldn't figure out why fastmm wasn't logging. Turns out, whoever wrote this code felt it needed `Windows.TerminateProcess` as part of its cleanup.

Comment: Ha, ha. Probably because the program was not terminating correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand which settings and `ini` file you are talking about. FastMM4 options are driven by compiler conditionals, IIRC.

The memory leaks are not tracked by default.

You need to compile your project with the `EnableMemoryLeakReporting` conditional explicitly enabled.

And possibly `LogMemoryLeakDetailToFile` and `FullDebugMode` conditionals too. With `FastMM_FullDebugMode.dll` and `FastMM_FullDebugMode64.dll` libraries in your executable folder, depending on your target platform.

And enable the "map file generation" level into "Detailed" in the project options, if you want line numbers for the stack trace.

See [this article](https://www.atozed.com/2021/07/detecting-memory-leaks-in-delphi-applications-using-fastmm-4/) and other similar as reference.

Comment: "*I don't understand which ... ini file you are talking about*" - the OP probably meant an .INC file, not an .INI file.

Comment: EnableMemoryLeakReporting is already defined, as shown in my Question.

Comment: Remy is right, I meant Inc, not Ini. Question fixed. Sorry.

Comment: @arnaud - Actually, you don't need the DLL in executable's folder if the inc file is properly set. You can also have it in executable's folder, but it is not mandatory (again, if the inc file is properly set).

Comment: @arnaud - The article you link to say that Debug information under Linking is necessary. Do you know why? I disagree with that (but activated it for a test anyway) :)

Comment: you did not write about EnableMemoryLeakReporting in your initial revision of the question, so I was confused when I answered it

Comment: My very first post stated "I use the same FastMM settings (inc) for all other projects, it works". So, FastMM inc file is properly set.